# Nil object reference in objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, null

I am calling a class method from an outside class in order to obtain an object reference, in this case a reference to a UIImage.  I can successfully call it and get it back from within `myOtherClass` itself, but when I call the method from `myClass`, it always returns nil.

```
@implementation myClass
...
- (UIImage *) gethThumb: (UIImage *) originalImage {

     // always comes back nil:
     UIImage* thumb = [MyOtherClass makeThumb: originalImage];
     return thumb;
}
...
@end

@implementation MyOtherClass

 ...
+ (UIImage*) makeThumb: (UIImage *) fullImage  {
    CGSize imageSize = [fullImage size];
    int shortestEdge = MIN(imageSize.width, imageSize.height);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake((imageSize.width - shortestEdge)/2, (imageSize.height - shortestEdge)/2, shortestEdge, shortestEdge);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([fullImage CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    CGSize thumbsize = CGSizeMake(180, 180);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(thumbsize);
    [thumb drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, thumbsize.width, thumbsize.height)];
    UIImage *scaledThumb = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //scaledThumb is not nil here:
    return scaledThumb;
}
...
@end
```

I stepped through and watched the value, I could see it was pointing to a valid memory address while still inside the makeThumb method, but once it had returned the pointer to the external class, the memory address was suddenly 0.

I tried writing it as an instance method and instantiating an object and then calling the method using

```
thumb = [self.myInstanceOfOtherClass makeThumb: originalImage];
```

and also changing the method to accept an object reference:

```
UIImage *thumbRef = nil;
thumb = [self.myInstanceOfOtherClass makeThumb: originalImage thumbRef:thumbRef];
```

-- in the myOtherClasss:

```
- (UIImage*) makeThumb: (UIImage *) fullImage thumbRef:(UIImage *) thumbRef {
    ...
    thumbRef = scaledThumb;
    ...
}
```

... which I thought would prevent ARC from losing the reference to the object (if that's what's happening here).

I am relatively new to Objective C, and I'm hoping someone can explain to me why this is happening.  Is the object being deallocated before it returns to the external class?  Do I have to turn it into a property that is strong in the external class so the reference doesn't get discarded?

Forgot to mention: the reference is pointing to an image being created from a reference to a camera image in the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.  The Camera UIView is dismissed before this thumb is created.  I think maybe this is why I am losing the reference.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: #tumbleweeds, #crickets

Comment: When I step through the code using the debugger the return value has a valid address when it is set, but then the debugger goes to the closing brace, and then bounces back to the return value, at which point in the console view one can see the value is set to 0x00000000 before actually returning to the calling method.  I believe ARC is doing this and I'm not sure how to work around it.  It even sets the reference to 0 for the thumbRef that was sent in by another class.

Comment: try doing __strong UIImage* thumb = [MyOtherClass makeThumb: originalImage]; and see if it still is nil.

Comment: Otherwise try doing __strong UIImage *scaledThumb = ...

Comment: It was nil when it left the makeThumb method, but it had a memory address when viewing it back in the calling code.

Comment: what does `__strong UIImage* thumb` do that `@property (strong, ...) UIImage *thumb` doesn't do?

Comment: Ok this is weird, in my getThumb the reference gets set to a valid memory address after calling makeThumb.  But later on, when I do a loadView, the reference is once again nil.  !!

Comment: I'm thinking maybe you're getting bit by ARC somehow.

Comment: That's what I think.  ARC is clearing the reference before leaving the function.  It doesn't clear it if its own class is calling it.

Comment: `__strong` is the default.  (`__strong UIImage* thumb` is the same as `UIImage* thumb`).

Answer (score -2):

You never allocated the memory for image. DO the following:

```
UIImage *myimage =[ [ UIImage alloc] init].
```